# Можно ли добавить событие нажатия клавиши в textbox в проекте ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

С кнопкой можно сделать так:

```
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate> 
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Кликаем по кнопке, отправляется асинхронный запрос, на сервере выполняется соответствующая функция и что-то записывается в label.

Можно ли сделать так: помещаем в UpdatePanel textBox и GridView, набираем текст в textBox, на каждое нажатие отправляется запрос на сервер в функцию, которая заполняет GridView. Но в проекте ASP.NET нет события KeyUp для элемента управления textbox.